# How to execute a method outside of run() in a backgroud thread?

Tags: java, android, sockets, background-thread

I have socket connection established. I have service running which receives the intent from activity to start the `SO Connection`. I understood that `socket` connection should be in background thread. My socket connects properly. Now I would like to send some bytes using `outputstream`. This is where I am running into problem.

```
public class myLocalThread extends Thread {

    private InetAddress serverAddress;
    private int serverPort;

    Socket clientSocket;
    BufferedInputStream inputStream;
    BufferedOutputStream outputStream;

    @Override
    public void run(){

        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket(serverAddress, serverPort);
            outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Start thread for receiving messages
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                int bytes_read = 0;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                while(true) {
                    try {
                        if ((bytes_read = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0){

                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
           }
        }.start();
    }

  public void outputMessage(byte[] message) throws IOException {
        outputStream.write(new byte[]{
                (byte) 0x01
        });
        outputStream.flush();
    }
}
```

I have setup intent for `outputMessage`, whenever I access this method, I am running into `Mainthread` again. I don't understand it(this is a background thread, isnt it ?). How can I acccess this method in my thread ? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I access the Intent using broadcastReceiver as follows

```
 public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        myLocalThread thread;
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if(action.equals("com.example.app.START")){
         thread = new myLocalThread();
         thread.start(); 
        } else if (action.equals("com.example.app.SEND")){
            try {
                thread.sendMessage(new byte[]{
                        (byte) 0x02
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where have u invoked `outputMessage` ? Post a little bit of code..

Comment: If you want to access it from your thread you should call it from the run method of your thread.

Comment: @NAIT you mean at the end like this ? `run(){  this.outputMessage() }`

Comment: the outputmessage method should be invoked inside the `run` method of the thread

Comment: @SantanuSur something like this `run(){this.outputMessage()}` ? or can you show me how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to call it from the `run` method of your thread as mentionned in the comments on your post.

There is also something weird in your code that I don't understand, why do you create a thread inside the `run` method. Is this something you're doing in purpuse ? Beacause this will create 2 threads each time you call `start` on `myLocalThread`.

In the code bellow I deleted the use of the second thread inside the run method and added the call the outputMessage method, I haven't tried this code so I just for illustrating purses.

Something like this

```
public class myLocalThread extends Thread {

    private InetAddress serverAddress;
    private int serverPort;

    Socket clientSocket;
    BufferedInputStream inputStream;
    BufferedOutputStream outputStream;

    @Override
    public void run(){

        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket(serverAddress, serverPort);
            outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        int bytes_read = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        while(true) {
             try {
                   if ((bytes_read = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0){

                   }
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
        }
        outputMessage(new byte[]{(byte) 0x01});

    }

    public void outputMessage(byte[] message) throws IOException {
        outputStream.write(message);
        outputStream.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to avoid running into `MainThreadException`. thats the reason I created the second thread

Comment: I couldnt call the method `outputMessage()`. Should I pass in bytes ?

Comment: Yes You can pass the bytes to the ouputMessage from the run method.

Comment: But I dont want to send it like that. I want to send the bytes once I click a button by receiving intent.

Comment: I edited the message abouve to call using a byte array

Comment: I have multiple byte arrays. I use to send it individually using different buttons.

Comment: Ok I see well then you should consider creating a Queue (a queue of byte arrays for instance) and passing it to the constructor on your thread then in your thread you can dequeu your queue. The queue will be filled by the main thread and dequed by MyLocalThread.

Comment: `myLocalThread() {  sendMessage(new byte[259]) }`. Will it be a good appraoch ? in the constructor of my thread

Comment: I don't get it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197159/discussion-between-cantona-7-and-nait).